How to fix a grainy font on RedHat Linux 8?
The fonts on my machine look grainy and pixelated. I have the default settings  for RHEL 8, with the Window Title/Document/Interface Fonts all set to Cantarell Bold with size 13.
I've tried changing the scaling but it hasn't changed the pixelation of the fonts. I have tried various other default fonts but they all look similarly grainy and pixelated. I have a 1080p 13.3 inch display, so I don't think they should look so pixelated. This is particularly apparent when using Google Chrome, where all website fonts are looking grainy. I've attached a picture of a webpage for reference.
How can I fix this? Is there any way to get a font like Times New Roman? Or a way to decrease the pixelation of the current fonts?
